# Как в django создать страницу с шаблонами и передать её через ajax?

Tags: python, django

В общем, как отправить просто html и вставить его на страницу я знаю, мне нужно чтоб с помощью шаблона(который еще язык шаблонизатора) генерировалась карточка товара в html и передавать это на страницу, или так сделать нельзя и придется просто отправлять данные и там уже их вставлять через js?

Comment: на уже загруженную страницу без участия JS ничего вставить нельзя

Comment: @МихаилРебров, тогда сделаю как я предложил во втором варианте